# Implementing Real-time Timer Functionality with Azure Functions, SignalR, and Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, signalr, real-time

I am working on a project where I need to create a real-time meeting timer functionality using **Azure Functions**, **SignalR**, and **Python**. The goal is to enable meeting attendees to play, pause, stop, or reset the timer for the overall meeting or specific meeting topics. The timer should be updated every second from the **server side**, ensuring **synchronization** among all meeting attendees.

I attempted to implement SignalR broadcast functionality using a **Timer trigger** for Azure Functions. However, I am uncertain about how to manually initiate and terminate the Timer trigger function. Additionally, I need to store timer-related information such as start time, end time, and elapsed time in the database. I expect to achieve a real-time, synchronized meeting timer functionality where attendees can interact with the timer, and updates are broadcast to all participants through SignalR.

I would appreciate guidance on how to implement this solution, specifically how to achieve this using Azure Function and SignalR in Python. Additionally, any advice on efficiently updating the timer in real-time on the client side while maintaining **synchronization** among all meeting participants would be highly valuable.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.